# Trying to translate ReactScheduler used in Nextjs

Tags: npm, next.js, syncfusion

I'm trying to translate  @syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule scheduler into french using Next.js, which has server-side rendering. So I'm converting  @syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule basic code to make it run with server-side rendering in Next. I encounter data populating error in the data injection inside jsx tag for rendering the scheduler at return() method.The data is a basic JSON file imported inside the react functional component js file.

```
    import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./../../styles/agenda.module.css";
import * as React from "react";
import {
  ScheduleComponent,
  Day,
  Week,
  WorkWeek,
  Month,
  Agenda,
  Inject,
  Resize,
  DragAndDrop
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule";

import { extend, loadCldr, L10n } from "@syncfusion/ej2-base";
import { SampleBase } from "./sample-base";


import * as dataSource from "../../database/agenda_datasource.json";
import * as numberingSystems from "./../agenda-culture-files/numberingSystems.json";
import * as gregorian from "../agenda-culture-files/ca-gregorian.json";
import * as numbers from "../agenda-culture-files/numbers.json";
import * as timeZoneNames from "../agenda-culture-files/timeZoneNames.json";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';



//Dynamically import the Smart.Scheduler component
const Scheduler = dynamic(() => import("@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule"), {
  ssr: false, //no server-side rendering 

});

function AgendaWidget({}) {
  loadCldr(numberingSystems, gregorian, numbers, timeZoneNames);
// hoho ny tsy fahaizana ajax de atao manta be lo le traduction fa ra mazoto any aoriana de ito ny code snipet https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/localization/
L10n.load({
  fr: {
  ////.............. json translating contents
    },
    calendar: {
      today: "Aujourd'hui,Androany"
    }
  }
});
 var predatabase = dataSource;
 var database = {predatabase:this.data}
  return (
    
    <Scheduler
    width="100%"
    height="650px"
    selectedDate={new Date(2018, 1, 15)}
    ref={t => (this.scheduleObj = t)}
//why it can't find  database variable here
    eventSettings={database}
    locale="es"
  >
    <Inject
      services={[
        Day,
        Week,
        WorkWeek,
        Month,
        Agenda,
        Resize,
        DragAndDrop
      ]}
    />
  </Scheduler>
  );
}

export default AgendaWidget;


The error


   TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    
    This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window

 162 | });
  163 |  var predatabase = dataSource;
> 164 |  var database = {predatabase:this.data}
      |                                  ^
  165 |   return (
  166 |     
  167 |     <Scheduler
```

I know the database variable is outside of the return() scope, but how can I inject data inside it? Help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shared code snippet you have set “**this.data**” to the **predatabase** property of the **database** variable and it’s the root cause of the issue. You cannot use **this** in the functional component. Also, you didn’t have **data**-named variables in your shared code snippet. But, you have assigned “**this.data**” to the **predatabase** property. To resolve the problem you need to set the data source to the Schedule as shown in the below code snippet.

**Sample:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ej2-react-next-js-schedule-sample-1127783108

**[index.js]**

```
import * as dataSource from './datasource.json';

export default function Home() {
  var predatabase = extend([], dataSource.zooEventsData, null, true);
  const database = { dataSource: predatabase };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <ScheduleComponent width="100%" height="650px" selectedDate={new Date(2021, 1, 15)} locale="es" eventSettings={database}>
        <Inject services={[Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda, DragAndDrop, Resize]} />
      </ScheduleComponent>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Refer to the below UG for more details about binding data with the Schedule.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/schedule/data-binding/#data-binding

Answer (score 1):

You can import the datasource as shown in the below code snippet to resolve the reported error.

**Sample:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ej2-react-next-js-schedule-sample280399184

**[index.js]**

```
import * as timeZoneNames from "../culture-files/main/timeZoneNames.json";
import {default as dataSource} from './datasource.json';
import "../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/styles/material.css";
```

Kindly try the attached sample and let us know if you need any further assistance on this.

Comment: Thanks, how do the crud operations works with this scheduler if i use MongoDB locally ??